# MongoDb, explanation fo _fts index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, nestjs, full-text-search

I use NestJs, TypeOrm, MongoDb.
since TypeOrm does not support setting a type of indexes I use the wrapper to access MongoDB directly:

```
itemRepo.createCollectionIndexes([
    { key: { name: 'text' }, name: 'itemTextIndex', unique: true },
  ]);
```

- key: seems to be the index type
- name is just a name I can give the index

If I look at the index via MongoCompass I see this:
[image]

Its great I got the Text index, but what is _fts _ftsx and why is it `Compound`?
I want it to only be for the name field :/

Comment: Those are internal implementation details that are just being exposed to you as you are looking at the explain plan (which is about internal implementation by definition). You've successfully created the index that you've requested, though it's perhaps a bit odd to have it be `unique`. What sort of queries are you planning to execute and what sort of uniqueness are you looking to enforce here?

Comment: Were you trying to create an index for full text search?  If not, you probably meant to use `key: {name: 1}`

Comment: Yes for fulltext search, also Unique because I want to store item names like product information and have the user search partials of it, like Product Model X and Product Model Y and have the user find both if he searches for a Model